# Could m2eclipse (Maven) use Windows account to access Nexus?

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, nexus

I know how to set settings.xml for Maven to access Nexus. But is it possible to let m2eclipse to use Windows account to access Nexus? Because it's not convenient that users needs to put their account in settingx.xml. Anogher issue is security, I know how to to encrypt the password ( [Maven Password Encryption](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)), but it's really not convenient.

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>nexus-releases</id>
    <username>xxx</username>
    <password>xxx</password>
  </server>
  <server>
    <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
    <username>xxx</username>
    <password>xxx</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use the [User Token](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-usertoken.html) feature of Nexus Professional. You still have to have the token (but not the username and password from the active directory/windows sign on) in your settings.xml but you can use the Nexus Maven Plugin to get it updated each time you change the Windows password and reset the Nexus user token as required. So you can basically automate it cleanly.

Answer (score -1):

No. Only windows knows your password, and even, I hope it keeps only a hashed version of it.

And there is no API to retrieve it from a program.

So, your password is lost in windows memory, and you will never manage to retrieve it !

HIH

Comment: But we don't need to put proxy's username/password in settings.xml when we build it from Eclipse. I think Eclipse (m2eclipse) has the ability to get it ?

Comment: This is not how the Maven password usage works. It needs it in clear text or encrypted via Maven encryption..